# File Handling C++ Issue Will Only Append One Row

Tags: c++, file

I am trying the read a file with 5 rows of letters and 5 columns of numbers. I am only trying to append the letters to an array; however, only the first letter is appended. The text file format:

```
ABC 1 2 3 4 5
DEF 6 7 8 9 10
GHI 11 12 13 14 15
JKL 16 17 18 19 20
MNO 21 23 23 24 25
```

I have tried this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void getData(fstream &inf, string letters[], double numbers[][6], int count);

int main()
{
    int rows = 5;
    string letters[rows];
    double numbers[rows][6];
    fstream inFile;

    getData(inFile, letters, numbers, rows);
    return 0;
}

void getData(fstream &inf, string letters[], double numbers[][8], int amount)
{
    inf.open("data2.txt");

    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
    {

//Add only letters to the letters array

        inf >> letters[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
        {

//Add numbers with to corresponding letters

            inf >> numbers[i][j];
        }
    }

//Print statement

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << letters[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

The result:

```
ABC
"BLANK LINE"
"BLANK LINE"
"BLANK LINE"
"BLANK LINE"
```

Comment: you try to read 8 numbers in the loop but there are only 5 in each line

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: my apologies. it should be 6. My professor wants to extract the letters and add them to an array, and the numbers along with letters in a 2d array printed.

Comment: `ABC 1 2 3 4 5` is only 5 numbers after the 3 characters. Here you assume it is 8: `for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)`

Comment: It's 5 in file, should be 6, specified to be 7 in the beginning of the question, and 8 in code. Much confusion! You should really use a debugger and see for yourself what really is going on, and not listen to anyone's explanation!

Comment: For now, nevermind the numbers. Why won't the letters be appended to the letters array? After the first iteration, when i = 0, ABC gets added to letters[0]. Then it begins the 2d operation. Afterwards, the second iteration, should be DEC being appended to letters[1], but that doesnt occur.

Comment: If you try to read too many numbers, `inf >> numbers[i][j];` will fail when the next input is a string and `inf` will be in an error state that you need to clear. I suggest reading an entire line at a time then use `std::stringstream` to parse each line.

Comment: It is vital that a question accurately represent the problem at hand and only that problem. If it doesn't you will get answers that are correct, but focus on the wrong problem in the code. See [mre] for a tool to isolate the problem you're seeking help with. Often making the [mre] will reveal the problem in all its buggy glory and render the question obsolete.

Comment: "For now, nevermind the numbers" they cannot be ignored, because the way you wrote your code you will get nonsense output just like you do now when the amount of numbers doesnt match. You ask what is wrong with the code, and its just that.

Comment: My bad, but shouldnt the 2d array in the second dimension be 6? Because the letters and 5 numbers will be added

Comment: `for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)` if you read 6 numbers when there are only 5 its still wrong, and does explain the output you do get

Comment: there are only 5 numbers in each row to be added to `numbers`. The characters you read here `inf >> letters[i];`

Comment: Oh... I just realized. Im forgetting how to count because Im getting confused with arrays starting at index 0. I need to cram this into my head.

Comment: `int rows = 5; string letters[rows];` This is [not legal C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard). If your professor teaches you this, consider finding a better professor.

Comment: mistakes like this cannot be avoided completely. Making typos is common, you need to learn how to recover from them. If you use a debugger and step through the code line by line it will become obvious what is going wrong.

Comment: My professor is completely hands off. This is a teach yourself course. I wouldve dropped this class if my $300 hadnt gone down the drain. Now im just problem solving while asking for help online. This helps me learn also.

Comment: Sorry guys. I just realized this also. When reading the code more slowly, the "inf" will continue reading until the end of line. This whole time I assumed the inf file would "re-read" the line so it can put the letters into the 2d array along with the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

When input is in lines, I generally prefer to read it in lines, then parse the pieces of each line I read.

I'd also use `vector`s instead of arrays, if at all possible.

Finally, when you're dealing with data formatted like this, all the data in a line is usually related, so you typically want to store all that data in a record.

Based on that, I'd probably do something like this:

```cpp
// a record of one line's data:
struct line {
    std::string letters;
    std::vector<double> numbers;

    // read a line of data from a stream.
    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &in, line &l) {
        std::string buffer;
        std::getline(in, buffer);
        std::istringstream is(buffer);

        // read the letters
        is >> l.letters;

        // read the numbers:
        double d;
        while (is >> d)
            l.numbers.push_back(d);

        return in;
    }
};
```

With that, reading a file worth of records looks something like this:

```cpp
std::ifstream input("myfile.txt");

std::vector<line> lines{ std::istream_iterator<line>(input), {} };
```

Comment: I have considered vectors, but I kinda felt like it would be cheating and this is a first year programming class.

Comment: The modern C++ school of thought is start with `vector` and teach the stuff that's underneath `vector` later once the students have a good grip on how the language works.  After all, why teach internal combustion mechanics at the beginning of driving lessons?

Comment: @Nill2000: Unless using them has specifically been prohibited, I wouldn't consider ti cheating. If you're going to study C++, study C++; that essentially always means constant use of vector.

Comment: But also note that there are a lot of teachers who haven't gotten the memo yet and still teach C. Less sarcastically, redeveloping course material is expensive and time consuming work that doesn't pay very well.

Comment: No he hasn't prohibited vectors. I just assumed that he may assume that Im cheating because this is a first year course and the book doesn't cover vectors. I admit, using vectors would make the code much easier.

Comment: @Nill2000 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk When I started c++ I had the similar believe. I trusted what I was thaught and only now I see that it was all about writing c++ as if it was c. In hindsight it was my biggest mistake to avoid `std::vector`. The fun with c++ only starts when you start to appreciate what the standard library has to offer

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai
Thank you for your concern. I came from a python background and c++'s syntax structure is picky and weird. I'm trying the understand more of it and will practice more.

Comment: @Nill2000 the reverse path is also true. Coming in from picky languages like C and C++ I have a hard time wrapping my head around Python code. I spend a lot of time wondering "Where the <expletive deleted> did that come from?"